# Jar on other PC cant run

Tags: java, eclipse, file, class, jar

I made a runnable JAR in eclipse with the export option. When i run it, it seems to work fine. But when my friend tries to run it, it will give an error:

Could not find the main class: nl.xedus.battlex.java.WebBrowser. Program will exit

Heres the JAR:

http: //www.media fire.com/?zh4cr3dwiy53fqr

Comment: Dependent jar files may not be present on his machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare versions of JVM installed on your and your friend's machines. I believe that you compiled your class for newer version of JVM than one that your friend uses, so his JVM does not "see" the class.

Other possibility is that the jar file arrived to him corrupted. Ask him to send you his jar file and try to run it yourself.

You can check your version, and your friends version [here](http://javatester.org/version.html)